# RitaWordNet: getSynset() give nullpointer, but description and id is OK

Tags: java, wordnet

I can search for "health" but "health insurance" give me `NullPointerException` thrown by `getSynset()`.

I get the description of "health insurance" and id number 913346773. But I can't get anything from `getSynset()`. Any good ideas?

Solution: 
There is a function `ignoreCompoundWords(true)` by default, I set that to false in constructor and now it returns an array.

New problem:

I can search for "health" and "health insurance", but "Medicare" give me `NullPointerException` thrown by `getSynset()`. BUT during debug, the correct description and id is found, so I don't know why getSynset() returns null.

However, checking medicare at: http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=&o8=1&o1=1&o7=1&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=medicare&i=0&h=0#c I just saw that it has no hyponyms. This could be the reason it throws `NullPointerException`?